# How to fix error when enble compress_output to TRUE in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hi all I am a new of codeigniter I have issue when I enble compress_output to TRUE I got error with :

```
Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

How I shoul I do for fix this error ? help me please.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter seems to have its own method of gzipping its output (Why, I don't know, but I'm not very familiar with CI.)

Such an error can occur when PHP error messages screw up the compressed content. Adjusting error_reporting to E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE did the trick there.

Update: There also seems to be a CI config setting:

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```